# How to add object within list view item to new array list

Tags: android, object, android-listview, arraylist

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_box);
            dialog.setTitle("Wish List");

            TextView dialogText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
            Button dialogButtonYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_yes);
            Button dialogButtonNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_no);

            dialogButtonYes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ArrayList<Product> wishList = new ArrayList<Product>();
                    wishList.add() ***// HOW DO I ACCESS THE OBJECT AT THAT ITEM TO ADD IT TO THE WISHLIST***
                }
            });

            dialogButtonNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I don't know how to insert Object at that specific item click into the array list. How would I go about that?

I have all sorts of Objects saved up in different items through the list view but each item consists of a different object and when the user clicks yes from the dialog box on the specific item, I want to store that object in a new array list once again.

Thank You

Comment: AdapterView<T>.getItemAtPosition ....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the position parameter (arg2 in your example) in onItemClick to index into the main list. Then set a final variable to store the Product which can then be added in the dialog if desired:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Object o = myList.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    if (o instanceof Product) {
        final Product selectedProduct = (Product)o;
    }  
    // ... Create dialog etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the wishlist array outside of the click somewhere in the class

```
 myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            final Product product = adapter.getItem(arg2);

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_box);
            dialog.setTitle("Wish List");

            TextView dialogText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
            Button dialogButtonYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_yes);
            Button dialogButtonNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_no);

            dialogButtonYes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                      addToWishList(product);
                }
            });

            dialogButtonNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

somewhere in your activity or adapter

```
ArrayList<Product> wishList = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

have a method like this

```
public function addToWishList(Product product){
 wishList.add(product);
}
```